# PHP sql statement where clause to multiple array values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, pdo

How do i use where clause for array if value[3] has multiple data stored

```
$fsql="select * from Error where RptDatime = 201706091000 and partnumber like  ('$value[3]')";
$getResults = $conn->prepare($fsql);        
$getResults->execute();
$results = $getResults->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);    

foreach($results as $row)
{         
    $mac = $row['Machine'];                
    $id = $row['Id'];                
    echo 'ID:'.$id.'Machine Number :'.$mac;
}
```

Comment: Please learn about prepared Statements. What you are doing is not what prepared Statements means

Comment: Check this link:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368033/prepared-statements-with-dynamic-where-clause

Comment: $value[3] is an array of numbers ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex function instead of like. Below is the sample code for you.

```
$partnumner = [];

    foreach($value[3] as $v)
    {
        $partnumber[] = "*.".$v.".*";
    }

    $fsql="select * from Error where RptDatime = 201706091000 and partnumber REGEXP  '".implode("|",$partnumber)."'";
```

If you still wish to use like, you can follow the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732246/mysql-in-with-like)

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you have array of numbers so, first you should validate for expected data and then to implode it into comma separated string.

```
if(!isset($value[3])){
    return false;
}
if(!is_array($value[3])){
    return false;
}
foreach($value[3] as $number){
    if(!is_numeric($number)){
        return false;
    }
}
$numbers = implode(",",$value[3]);
$fsql=sprintf("select * from Error where RptDatime = 201706091000 and partnumber in  (%s)",$numbers);
$getResults = $conn->prepare($fsql);        
$getResults->execute();
$results = $getResults->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);    

foreach($results as $row)
{         
    $mac = $row['Machine'];                
    $id = $row['Id'];                
    echo 'ID:'.$id.'Machine Number :'.$mac;
}
```