# PHP SQL statement using REGEXP to fetch multiple values

Tags: php, sql, arrays, pdo

How do I use REGEXP to fetch multiple data from the array `$vall`.

I referred a sample code from: 
[PHP sql statement where clause to multiple array values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451887/php-sql-statement-where-clause-to-multiple-array-values/44452336#44452336)

Some of the sample data: CGCG-0025-0,CGCR-0003-0,CGRQ-0163-0

```
foreach ($list as $value) // this $list is from another array
{
    $part = $value[3];
    $vall[] = $value[3];  // $list1 is an empty array
}

$partnumber =[];

foreach($vall as $v)
{
    $partnumber[] = "*.".$v.".*";

    print_r(array_values($partnumber));   // these are some of the values Array ( [0] => *.CGCG-0025-0.* ) Array ( [0] => *.CGCG-0025-0.* [1] => *.CGCG-0025-0.* ) Array ( [0] => *.CGCG-0025-0.* [1] => *.CGCG-0025-0.* [2] => *.CGCR-0003-0.* )
}

foreach($partnumber as $x)
{
    echo '<br>'.$partnumber; // shows 'Array' on each lines 
}

$fsql="select * from Error where RptDatime = 201706091000 and partnumber REGEXP  '".implode("|",$partnumber)."'";

//example 1 $fsql="select * from MPdError where RptDatime = 201706091000 and partnumber = ('CGRQ-0057-0') ";
//example 1 shows the correct data but i need multiple partnumber
$getResults = $conn->prepare($fsql);
$getResults->execute();
$results = $getResults->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

foreach($results as $row)
{
    $mac = $row['Machine'];
    $id = $row['Id'];
    echo '<br><br><br>ID:'.$id.'<br>Machine Number :'.$mac;
}
```

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL-injection

Comment: Please add some sample data and teh expected result

Comment: `*.CGCG-0025-0.* ` is not a valid regular expression. `.*\.CGCG-0025-0\..*` would be a valid regular expression

Comment: I tried changing and still didnt work
 $partnumber[] = ".*\.".$v."\..*";

Comment: I don't understand why you need wildcards before and after the part number. What does `$v` contain, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this may not be a good solution as it contains a huge security risk, I will still post it based on what is needed above.

REGEXP is not needed for data that are not complex in design.

```
$fsql = "select * from Error where RptDatime = 201706091000 and partnumber in ('" . implode("','", $vall) . "');"
```